# sql инекции MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Если у меня на сайте нет, поля ввода, нужно писать защиту от sql инекций? они могут проникнуть через поля ввода или по разному?  бд MySql

Comment: Инъекции "проникают" через информацию, которая передаётся от пользователя. А как эта информация попадает на сервер - вводится через поле ввода или как часть URL,- не имеет никакого значения. И надо не писать защиту (хотя и не запрещено), а использовать средства, не подверженные инъекциям.

Comment: Как правильно написано выше, проблема не в том, откуда данные приходят, а в том, как происходит работа с запросами. Если правильно, то инъекции не страшны. А откуда пришли данные, из поля или из леса - совершенно неважно